# Circular progress bar with inner stroke

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to build a circular percentage chart like this:

[image: circular progress bar with inner stroke]

At the moment, I have this: https://jsfiddle.net/pvtxgq21/1/

HTML:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
  <path
    class="circle-outer"
    d="M18 2.0845
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
  />
  <path
    class="circle"
    stroke-dasharray="50, 100"
    d="M18 2.0845
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
  />
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 256px;
}

.circle-outer {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #3c3c3c;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #17E68F;
  stroke-width: 3;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}

.percentage {
  fill: #666;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

I can't find a way to "paint" the colored circle inside the other, as the picture above shows. I am not well versed in SVG. Is there a simple solution to this? Some SVG property that I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't understand what you need. You image and example are identical.

Comment: There is a slight difference. In the image, the green circle is inside the grey (the solution I am trying to achieve). In the example, the green circle is centered in the grey one.

Comment: you need to adjust the viewbox. (add overflow:visible to SVG to see the issue)

Comment: Nasty little problem (always). SVG puts the stroke 50% outside the fill and 50% over the fill. I have no solution, but this is what you need to google for "SVG stroke position outside" .

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thanks, I'll do some search.

Comment: One of the first links is a proposal for the exact thing that I needed, lol. https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Stroke_position To bad this property does not exist.

Comment: Can't remember where/when I did this, but your green circles' **r** needs to been half green stroke width in pixels smaller that the grey one. Bit of fiddling with pixels will help.

Comment: Suggestion: put the SVG inside a `<div>` and make `.circular-chart { width: 100% }` instead of `.circular-chart { max-width: 256px }` and resize or max the `<div>`, this way responsive design will become a tat more easy.

Comment: @RenevanderLende That's a good idea. I'll do that. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to rewrite the second path so that the circle's radius is 2 units smaller (stroke-width="3" - stroke-width="1")
2. Now the problem is that the length of the animated path is smaller so you need to change the animation too

```css
body {
      background-color: #000;
    }
    
    .circular-chart {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px auto;
      max-width: 256px;
    }
    
    .circle-outer {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #3c3c3c;
      stroke-width: 1;
    }
    
    .circle {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #17E68F;
      stroke-width: 3;
      stroke-dasharray: 0 93.73;
      animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes progress {
      100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 46.86;
      }
    }
    
    .percentage {
      fill: #666;
      font-size: 0.5em;
      text-anchor: middle;
    }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
      <path
        class="circle-outer"
        d="M18 2.0845
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <path
        class="circle"
        d="M18 3.0845
            a 13.9155 13.9155 0 0 1 0 29.831
            a 13.9155 13.9155 0 0 1 0 -29.831"
      />
    </svg>
```

Comment: That is the exact behaviour I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
<path
class="circle-outer"
d="M18 2.0845
    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
/>
<path
class="circle"
stroke-dasharray="70, 100"
d="M18 2.8
    a 15 15 0 0 1 0 30
    a 15 15 0 0 1 0 -30"
/>
</svg>
```

Hello. Use the above code in the `<svg>`. Hope it resolves your problem.